# Скрипт для простановки одинаковой ссылки у одинаковых докторов в разных таблицах, отобранных по фамилии имени отчеству

Tags: sql

Не могу понять, как написать следующий скрипт: есть 2 таблицы с докторами - Doctors1 и Doctors2. В этих таблицах есть поле ResourcesID (ссылка) и, соответственно, есть таблица Resources. Необходимо в таблицах Doctors1 и Doctors2 вставить уникальный ключ ResourceID для каждого доктора, при этом записи докторов в таблицах не уникальны и могут повторяться, т.е. Иванов Иван Иванович может быть несколько раз в Doctors1 и в Doctors2, но это один и тот же человек, поэтому ссылка ResourceID у него будет одна.
Входные данные для запросы - Name, FName, SName (фамилия, имя, отчество доктора). Необходимо создать запись в таблице Resource (поле nullable) и проставить ID созданной записи у одинаковых докторов в обоих таблицах.

Comment: вместо тысячи слов лучше пример таблиц с данными  привести

Comment: А таблица `Resource` и `ResourcesID` у докторов изначально пустые или частично уже заполненные? Так то вроде ничего сложного - отобрать уникальные сочетания ФИО из обоих таблиц, объединить их через `UNION`, пронумеровать, ну и дальше проставить в докторах эти `ID` через `UPDATE`

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035) Пункты 5 и 3.

Comment: @CrazyElf, они пустые изначально. Т.е. нужно вставить запись в Resources (с null, без разницы), и далее дать ResourceID доктору, при этом доктор может повторяться в этих 2-ух таблицах n раз.

Comment: @Дмитрий Ну тогда я выше вам описал примерный алгоритм. Начните делать, может сами по ходу дела разберётесь. Где не разберётесь - прикладывайте к вопросу код, будем помогать. Но начать что-то делать вы должны сами.

Comment: @CrazyElf а как учесть то, чтобы во всех повторяющихся записях докторов вставить один ID? В этом самая главная задача.

Comment: @Дмитрий Вы не знаете, как отобрать уникальные сочетания ФИО? `SELECT DISTINCT ...`, и используемый после этого `UNION` выкидывает дубликаты, так что в итоге все ФИО будут уникальными. Пронумеровать записи можно взяв `row number`, если в данном `SQL` есть такая функция. Если нет, то через оконную функцию его можно получить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вышло это:

```
select SName, Name, FName, row_number() over(order by ddd.SName, ddd.FName, ddd.Name) as id
into #res
from 
(select doctor.SName, doctor.Name, doctor.FName from dbo.Doctors1 doctor where doctor.IsDeleted = 0
  union all    
 select doctor.SName, doctor.Name, doctor.FName from dbo.Doctors2 doctor where doctor.IsDeleted = 0)
 as ddd
 group by SName, Name, FName
 order by 1
 
declare @Name NVARCHAR(100)
declare @FName NVARCHAR(100)
declare @SName NVARCHAR(100)
declare @ID INT
declare dbcurs cursor for
select * from #res
open dbcurs
fetch next from dbcurs into @SName, @Name, @FName, @ID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin 
update dbo.Doctors1 set ResourceID = @ID where Name = @Name and SName = @SName and FName = @FName
update dbo.Doctors2 set ResourceID = @ID where Name = @Name and SName = @SName and FName = @FName
insert into dbo.Resources values (@ID, null)
fetch next from dbcurs into @SName, @Name, @FName, @ID
end
close dbcurs
DEALLOCATE dbcurs

drop table #res
```

Все работает, как задумано. Спасибо за наводки.